# Django 'str' object has no attribute 'field' context

Tags: python, django, django-3.0

I have a problem, i got this error:
'str' object has no attribute 'field'

This is my views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Company
from .forms import NewCompanyForm

# Sociétés
def companies_index(request):
    companies_list = Company.objects.order_by('-id')
    context = {
        "companies_index": "active",
        'companies_list': companies_list,
    }
    return render(request, 'companies/index.html', context)

def companies_create(request):
    context = {
        "companies_create": "active",
    }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewCompanyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('companies_index')
    form = NewCompanyForm()

    return render(request,'companies/create.html',context,{'form': form})

def companies_delete(request, pk):
    company = get_object_or_404(Company, pk=pk)
    company.delete()
    return redirect('companies_index')
```

The problem is with the "create" action i want to know how i can pass the context variable and the form variable to my template.

Best regards.

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It's about the render method

render(request, template_name, **context**=None)

> **context**
>
> A dictionary of values to add to the template context. By
> default, this is an empty dictionary. If a value in the dictionary is
> callable, the view will call it just before rendering the template.

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#render

---

One solution could be:

```
def companies_create(request):
    payload = dict()
    payload['context'] = {
        "companies_create": "active",
    }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        payload['form'] = NewCompanyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('companies_index')
    form = NewCompanyForm()

    return render(request,'companies/create.html', payload)
```

Note that **payload** is a dictionary you are providing for the positional argument **context**.

Now you may pass any number of context variables to the template without trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
return render(request,'companies/create.html',{'context':context, 'form': form})
```

The 3rd argument of render is a dictionary so anything you want to send to template should be pack in dictionary. This will solve your problem.